# LTspice simulation of third-party op-amp throws "time step too small error"

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

The circuit which I am simulating here is a Strain Gauge Bend sensor module Y3 which I bought and is working well.

Now I want to integrate it within my circuit and it was better to add it in the design phase into my circuit instead of attaching it as an external module because I have a lot more modules to attach also. The circuit diagram which I got online for the device is below:

[image]

Now I want to simulate this in LTspice and I followed the procedure to install 3rd-party libraries for the LM358 op-amp using the PSpice libraries which I got online. The simulation for the TL431 however was successful; it was the op-amp which was the problem.

The library for the LM358 PSpice is from this [TI website](https://www.ti.com/product/LM358).

My schematic is as follows and in this version I replaced the op-amp with an AD820 because online forums showed that this might be a better approximation to the original one:

[image]

This simulation works well and does yield a somewhat similar result to what I expected but I can't add an input voltage of more than 3 V and the simulation does not show any output.

So the first thing I don't understand is why is this happening.

Next, when I simulate by replacing the AD820 with the LM358 3rd-party version, I get a time step too small error:

[image]

The above schematic is just a simple one where I use a UniversalOpAmp2.asy and change the directory to the new library which I got online and whose working is shown above.

Upon performing the simulation the error which I get is as shown:

[image]

I tried following a lot of videos online and other forums but the problem remains the same. I tried creating a symbol for this instead of using the UniversalOpAmp2 and changing directory, but the error remains the same and it would be very good if someone could help me solve this issue with a possible explanation on what was the mistake from my side so that I can learn.

Comment: Did you try running a simulation with the op amp in a circuit, not just on its own?

Comment: @Hearth 
I tried running it in the original circuit and not just on its own but the error is still the same

Comment: I had the same  problem with MCP6001 opamp. The way I solve it is finding another model. Maybe you can try model of onsemi.

Comment: What happens if you add the following SPICE directive to the schematic?: `.options cshunt=1p`

Comment: Also, why is your VCC so low?  It's 1V and through a silicon PN diode.  That's rather low to operate an opamp off of.

Comment: @Ste Kulov. Sorry it was my mistake. The opamp voltage should have been set to 3V. Simulation works with 3V. I was trying to get used to the software and what the simulation outputs. I noticed that the simulation also does not work when the voltage is set to more than 3.5V and it outputs no result in the simulation window. Any help on this problem would also be good.

Comment: @Willis Lin  
I will try to find online whether there is any equivalent version of what I am using.

Comment: I find the usable model of LM358 from ONSEMI. Do you need me to send you the file?

Comment: Did you try the first thing I asked you about?  You didn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second AD820 should be supplied with 1.25 V (**VFF/2**) at **V+ input** in place of VFF.

As this around RP1-C5 (**1.25 V**) in place of VPP ...
and your C7 should be disconnected and placed in parallel with your R4.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Time step too small sometimes indicates a real problem with the circuit.

You also should have Vdd at least 3V (preferably a bit more) after the diode for the LM358 (and supply a diode model, not the default, such as 1N4148 if you insist on using a diode at all).

The main other problem I see is that the 1uF load capacitor should **not** be on the op-amp output- it will surely cause oscillation. If you want to slow the response, use a cap parallel to the feedback resistor.